# URL key is already in use by another blog item

Tags: magento2, custom, custom-theme, url-key, blog

[image]

Anyone can help me to fix this problem ?

Comment: Please check  url_rewirte table for duplicated URL ?

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this issue, you need to change the URL key for the new blog post or page to a unique value.

**Steps to do it**:

1. Go to the backend of your Magento store and navigate to the "**Content**" section.
2. Select the blog post or page that you want to edit.
3. In the "**General Information**" section, find the "**URL Key**" field and change it to a unique value.
4. **Save** the changes to the blog post or page.

Once you have made the changes, clear the cache in Magento to ensure the changes take effect.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try bin/magento c:f ? You should get the same result .
Seems like you already duplicate Posts or Blog Categories .